# css3 converting matrix3d values

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style, css, 3d

I want to know how to get the rotateX and rotateY values of a matrix3d such as this:

```
matrix3d(0.9999999970415847, 0, 0.00007692093651178932, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.00007692093651178932, 0, 0.9999999970415847, 0, 0, 0, 300, 1)
```

does anybody know how to this ? I would really appreciate the help especially since I am not really the math type of person. thnx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not good at math either, so this needs some checking by someone with more knowledge than me:

```
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(el.style.webkitTransform);
var rotationX = Math.acos(matrix.a) * (180/pi);
var rotationY = Math.asin(matrix.b) * (180/pi);
```

You can view a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YsCF5/

Comment: A quick note, this was written a long time ago and the CSSMatrix feature was a non-standard proposal. MDN now recommends the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix