# Axis of rotation seems to change inconsistently.

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, rotation

I'm experiencing a bit of weirdness. I have a cube on the page, that can be rotated in 2 ways:

1. if the user mouses around near an edge of the cube, it will "tip" in that direction, exposing the hidden side of the cube.
2. If the cube is currently "tipped" and the exposed side of the cube is clicked, the cube will rotate so that this side is facing the user.

```js
// on mouse enter, "tip" the cube to expose the nearest hidden face
$(".overlay").mouseenter(function () {
    var direction = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
    var tease = getTease(direction);

    $("#cube").css({ transform: 'translateZ(-100px) ' + tease });
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("teasing");

// on mouse leave, reset the cube
}).mouseleave(function () {

    $("#cube").css({ transform: 'translateZ(-100px) rotateX(' + rotateX + 'deg) rotateY(' + rotateY + 'deg)' });
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("teasing");
});

// if the user clicks the exposed side of a cube, rotate that side to face them
$(document).on("click", ".overlay.teasing", function () {
    var direction = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
    var rotate = getRotate(direction);

    $("#cube").css({ transform: 'translateZ(-100px) ' + rotate });
});
```

If you rotate to the left or right, everything works fine. If you rotate the cube around the X axis (rotating it away or towards the user), then suddenly the "tipping" is broken on the left and right sides. I imagine that this is a problem with my understanding. At first I thought the answer was that, when the cube is rotated around the X axis, the Y axis itself rotates to point towards the user. This would explain why the cube now tips in the wrong direction: it is tipping around a Y axis that is directed at the user. However, on further experimenting I noticed that this behaviour is not consistent between the X and Y axis. That is to say, spinning the cube left/right and then up/down works fine. Spinning the cube up/down and then left/right is broken.

Does anyone understand why?

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hy2Sb/9/) of my little experiment (tested in webkit and gecko). Apologies for the mess: I've tried to comment it as well as possible, because it just represents me messing around for a couple of hours and isn't the prettiest code.

**note**: I notice this question has been asked in one way or another a number of times on SO, but I haven't found a satisfying answers. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614162/controling-css-cube-rotationtransform-and-extracting-values-from-3d-matrix?lq=1) in particular is full of useful information and tutorials. I'm sure I could implement the solution that uses matrixes. What I'm interested in, in my particular case, is why the cube works fine with left/right then up/down, but not the other way.

Comment: It's all about point of reference. You are spinning items along a 3-dimensional plane, and so when you "rotate up", but then want to rotate left, it is performing the function you ask, but it is relative to the way it was originally facing. This means that the new X-axis was your original Z-axis, and therefore you need to identify when this "alternative X-axis" is in existence, and rotateZ instead of rotateX accordingly. Something along those lines, at least.

Comment: I don't have the time to work something like that out, but that concept will hopefully get you rolling in the right direction. I have also cleaned up your code a bit => http://jsfiddle.net/Hy2Sb/11/

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Thanks for the feedback! I understand this concept. However, why is it that when you rotate left, and then up, it works... but not when you rotate up and then left? I would expect that rotating left would point the x-axis at the user, and then rotating "up" around the x-axis would appear to be a tilt to the left or right (as is the case for the up then left action). Do you have any idea?