# famo.us - multiple rotation - switching axis

Tags: rotation, matrix-multiplication, famo.us

I started playing with famo.us and created cube which rotates left/right or up/down when pressing buttons.

rotation left:

```
y+=-Math.PI/2;
trans=Transform.rotate(x,y,z);
```

rotation top:

```
x+=-Math.PI/2;
trans=Transform.rotate(x,y,z);
```

this works in one direction, but if I turn up and than turn left if does not produce desired result because axis are changing with first rotation. So basically it rotates around wrong axis

there is similar thread here [Controling CSS cube rotation(transform) and extracting values from 3d matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614162/controling-css-cube-rotationtransform-and-extracting-values-from-3d-matrix)

but it is using pure css transformations and compositing rotations. I wonder if it can be fixed easily with some famo.us matrix multiplication or using quaternions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use a `Modifier` with it's `transformFrom` to control your cube rotation as was done in the examples. Then we will use the `Quaternion` to return a transform based on a multiplier `Quarternion`.

### [Example and running code here](http://jsbin.com/lovuv/1/edit?js,output)

#### Setup our Quaternions

```js
var quaternion = new Quaternion(1, 0, 0, 0);
var moveQuaternion = new Quaternion(185, 0, 0, 0);
```

#### Setup our rotation Modifier

```js
  var rotationModifier = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0.5],
    align: [0.5, 0.5]
  });
```

#### Transform from the quaternion

```js
  rotationModifier.transformFrom(function() {
    return quaternion.getTransform();
  });
```

#### Calculate the `quaternion` using a multiplier on engine tick

```js
  Engine.on('prerender', function() {
    // You combine rotations through quaternion multiplication
    quaternion = quaternion.multiply(moveQuaternion);
  });
```

#### Add the rotation Modifier and Box to the context

```js
 mainContext.add(rotationModifier).add(createBox(260, 260, 260));
```

#### Here is our key controller event handler

```js
  Engine.on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log('keyEvent',e.keyIdentifier);
    var x = quaternion.x;
    var y = quaternion.y;
    var z = quaternion.z;
    switch (e.keyIdentifier) {
      case 'Up':
        x = -1; y = 0; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'Down':
        x = 1; y = 0; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'Left':
        x = 0; y = 1; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'Right':
        x = 0; y = -1; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'Home':
        x = -1; y = 1; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'PageUp':
        x = -1; y = -1; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'End':
        x = 1; y = 1; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'PageDown':
        x = 1; y = -1; z = 0;
        break;
      case 'Clear':
        x = 0; y = 0; z = 0;
        break;
      default:
        x = 1; y = 1; z = 1;
    }
        moveQuaternion = new Quaternion(185, x, y, z);
    });
```

Comment: Interaction seems to work fine but I think there is still problem of changing axis. For instance, when I rotate to the moment when see top side of cube and than rotate Right - it rotates around my z-axis and I would like to  rotate it around y-axis. And one more extra question - Would it be possible to lock rotation with Quaternion. For instance, when pressing Right - rotate just 90 degree and stop ? thx

Comment: It is rotating with respect to the origin view.  Be aware that in this example the view side of the axis is at the front of the cube (in this case orange side), so there is a change in direction with respect to that view because that is the start of the quarternion.